# integrating neo4j DB with laravel 5

Tags: php, neo4j, laravel-5

I think that some of you might have tried [this](https://github.com/endyjasmi/neo4j/wiki/) to integrate `neo4j` with `laravel 5`. Here is what I did:
I installed laravel 5 by using this command: 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel5test dev-develop`
It got installed smoothly without any errors. 
I went through wiki, added `"endyjasmi/neo4j": "2.*"` to `require` section in `composer.json`, ran `composer update`. And it was installed successfully, then I added 
`'EndyJasmi\Laravel\Neo4jServiceProvider'`
to `providers` section in `app/config/app.php`. I didn't add facades because I don't intend to use them. ( I hope that adding facades is optional! )
Then I went to `app/config/database.php`, added

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Neo4j Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Neo4j is an open source graph database which is
    | very fast in traversing related data
    |
    */

    'neo4j' => [
        'default' => 'development',

        'profiles' => [
            'development' => [
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 7474,
                'username' => '',
                'password' => ''
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

to `connections` array. Then I gave default as 
`'default' => 'development'`

Then I thought of testing all those modifications, so I fired up local php server by using 
`php artisan serve`
and this is the error which I got:

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method [bind]' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/endyjasmi/neo4j/src/Laravel/Neo4jServiceProvider.php(43): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->__call('bind', Array)
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/endyjasmi/neo4j/src/Laravel/Neo4jServiceProvider.php(43): EndyJasmi\Laravel\Neo4jServiceProvider->bind('EndyJasmi\Neo4j...', 'EndyJasmi\Neo4j...')
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(415): EndyJasmi\Laravel\Neo4jServiceProvider->register()
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(536): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->register(Object(EndyJasmi\Laravel\Neo4jServiceProvider))
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(518): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerDeferredProvider('EndyJasmi\Larav...', 'EndyJasmi\Neo4j...')
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(492): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->loadDeferredProvider('EndyJasmi\Neo4j...')
#6 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->loadDeferredProviders()
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravel5login/artisan(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 {main}
```

Where did I do mistakes? in `app.php`? or in `database.php`? Please help me out

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent. It's an excelent package for using Neo4J with Laravel 5

Comment: I have been using the same and this is exactly what you would need. Along with good documentation, the package is extremely stable to this date (using on laravel 5.3)

Comment: In laravel 5 may I write query in SQL for neo4j database. If I want to create node than may I write  SQL code and neoEloquent convert it to neo4j instead of $user = User::create(['name' => 'Some Name', 'email' => 'some@email.com']); does it possible to use neo4j without using core laravel Eloquent ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

Lavarel 5 have some changes, you should try this OGM, https://github.com/lrezek/Neo4Laravel. Also checkout the pull which fixed for Lavarel > 5